# UTM Tags and Anchors in URL

Tags: url, google-analytics, anchor, expressionengine

In my work we use a CMS, and I'm not entirely sure how everything is set up, but I'm having issues using anchors in my links. For example, when I have a link to another portion of the site and I try to append an anchor, such as `mysite.com#video-anchor`, the url inside of the `<a></a>` tags gets appended with UTM tags: "mysite.com/utm_campaign=...", and the `#video-anchor` just doesn't show up in the final URL. The result is just linking to the page, but without scrolling to the anchor that I specified. Any help?

Answer (score 7):

You should use the #anchor parameter at the end, with the UTM after the URL, like this

www.yousite.com/page?utm_source=XXX&utm_medium=XXX&utm_campaign=XXX#video-anchor

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like an issue with the CMS rather than anything to do with Google Analytics. I would contact support for the CMS, or edit your question title nad tag to include the name of the CMS.

Answer (score 0):

Anchors don't work as they usually do when you add utm's to a URL. In fact, they break the UTM altogether. Make sure you're adding the anchor to the end of the UTM query string if you want it to work. This Webmasters post should help:

https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/35413/13067

Comment: Thanks for your response. However the problem I'm having is when I'm setting a link via the <a></a> tags. How do I specify an anchor in a link where the UTM tags have not been added yet?